# Ошибка кодировки при переносе проекта на flask на сервер

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Делаю небольшой проектик на flask. Сначала делал на компьютере под Windows 10 в pycharm - все работает нормально, потом пришло время выкатить на сервер - ничего не работает и выдает вот такие ошибки при попытке выполнения некоторых действий:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   0-5: ordinal not in range(128)

Насколько мне удалось понять, подобные ошибки происходят при обработке присланных из форм данных и при попытке записи в базу данных (на sqlite3). Но это не точно. Все файлы вроде бы в UTF-8, не знаю даже в какую сторону копать и что делать.

Ошибка происходит во многих местах, но вот один пример:

```
project_queries = str(project_queries) + str(q.query_text) + '\n'
```

Это строчка из функции:

```
def get_project_by_id(id):
    session = Session(bind=engine)
    project_data = session.query(Project).filter(Project.id == id).first()
    project_queries_in_list = session.query(Phrase).filter(Phrase.project == id, Phrase.enable == True).all()

    project_queries = ''

    for q in project_queries_in_list:
        project_queries = str(project_queries) + str(q.query_text) + '\n'


    project_info = {'id': project_data.id, 'name': project_data.name, 'domain': project_data.domain, 'queries': project_queries}
    session.close()
    return project_info
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81222/discussion-on-question-by-------).